# Textbox that accepts all the characters but returns only numbers

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need the code to filter the data entered in a textbox. Although it accepts all the characters during runtime, the code should remove all the strings and alpha numeric characters except the numbers (which would be my output). I tried the following code but guess it won't do:

```
a = Textbox1.text
Dim value As Decimal = CDec(Regex.Replace(a, "[\D]", ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex was correct (just a bit redundant, `\D` would have done). Better would have been `\D+` so consecutive non-decimals are replaced at once.

```
ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, "\D+", "")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) that was quick. I tried it, but it still does not workout. Any ideas? or a different approach I should try?

Comment: Perhaps you could be a bit more specific. "It doesn't work" is not helpful. What do you get for `ResultString` when `SubjectString` is set to, say, `"123abc456 =?789"`?

Comment: Sorry my bad :) well, the output is same as input, if I enter "123abc" I want the result to be "123", however, it still is "123abc". I tried Inputbox for a change but it still is the same.

Comment: Are you assigning the calculated value back to Textbox1? So I mean have you added this line after your original code: Textbox1.Text = value

Answer (score 0):

I use this jQuery plugin. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryNumberLettersPlugin

$("#id").numbers();

That would only allow numbers to be entered into the selected input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, use the matching object

```
Dim a As String
Try
    a = Regex.Match(Textbox1.text, "\d+").Value     
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    'Syntax error in the regular expression
End Try
```